# error in unity package "terrain sample asset" version: 2022.1.16f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I install terrain simple asset and give me an error:
An error occurred while resolving packages:
Project has invalid dependencies:
com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition: Package [com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@12.1.0] cannot be found

I'm on version 2022.1.16f1 on a 3D URP project. When i restart the project its saying [Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzYv4.png)

I dont know what to do i check on internet but no one have the same error than me.
(sorry for my bad english) and have a good day!

Comment: From your error message, it is importing a High Definition Render Pipeline (HDRP) asset into your project. But your project is using the Universal Render Pipeline (URP). HDRP and URP don't work together. See if there is a URP version of "terrain simple asset" you can import instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you ever solved this issue but I stumbled across this post when I had it myself so I'll pop this here for anybody who has this issue in the future. it seems that the sample terrain tools has URP, HDRP, and SRP dependencies when importing, so simply go into your package manager to the 'in project' window and remove whichever of these you aren't using and it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big problem that Unity dropped the ball on. I tried installing the terrain sample asset pack into a new project (unity 2023.1) that was using the built-in rendering pipeline, and the same thing kept happening -- the extra terrain brushes were missing, and I was also getting errors about the HDRP and the URP, even though I hadn't installed/enabled them.

Turns out that the package manager *insists* on importing "package dependencies" and those dependencies apparently include the HDRP and URP rendering pipelines. Once I told Unity NOT to install the package-manager dependencies, everything went smoothly and I was able to access the upgraded stamps/brushes as usual.